# Не отображается форма на веб страничке. Только кнопка submit

Tags: python, html, django, forms

Файл views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render     
from .forms import ReplyForm


def create(reqeust):
    form1 = ReplyForm()

    data = {
        'form1': form1
    }

    return render(reqeust, 'forma.html', data)
```

Файл forms.py

```
from .models import Reply
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput, EmailInput


class ReplyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reply
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'text']
```

Html шаблон

```
<main>
   <form method='post' class="form">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {{ form1.as_p }}
       <button type="submit">Submit</button>
     </form>
</main>
```